# Logic Pro X workflow options for multi-track live recordings

Tags: workflow, logic-pro, logic, multichannel

I'm new to live multi-track recording and wondering what workflow options are available in Logic for post processing. I have 16 tracks recorded live for 60+ minutes but I don't want to work with 60+ minute segments. What I'm wondering is what options exist in Logic for breaking things up by song across all 16 tracks. Ideally it would be one project per song. Does that make sense? Is there a way to pull parts of all 16 tracks at once? Perhaps by marker?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this all the time. Position the playhead at a convenient/natural point between songs, select all the regions,  and "Split Region(s)". At this point you will have a "song" and "the rest of the audio". Place a marker on the first set of regions. Make the song work. When you are satisfied create a new "Alternative" and move to the next song (position playhead, split, make marker, etc.)

Settings carry forward to each alternative, but changes only happen to the "current" alternative. You can easily get to the starting point of any song by choosing the appropriate alternative (name them the same as the song).

If you ever need to isolate the tracks for one song you can select the regions and bounce them into files (LPX 10.2.3) and make a new project with just those files.

Comment: I haven't played with alternatives but that sounds like that would work well! 

There are those times when a song may segue into another and I want to save off individual songs. Typically that involves doing some volume manipulations for certain tracks to limit the segue bleed but that wouldn't be appropriate for the next song when it comes time to saving that one off. Alternatives sound like just the ticket.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If it is all one band doing one contiguous concert, I wouldn’t want to break that up into 16 projects, because you will likely want to treat each channel in basically the same way. It likely really is just one drum recording, one guitar recording, and so on, even though it is many songs. If you split it up, the things you do to the drum track, you might have to do again in the other 15 projects.

I would just set markers at the top of each song, then make broad mixing changes like per-channel EQ and compression and a rough fader volume that applies well to all 16 songs, and then later select each marker in turn, turn on loop, focus on that one song, and use automation to make per-song fader adjustments as required.

You can show the marker track at the top of the timeline, and there is also a marker list that makes it easy to navigate.